# Comparing current row and previous row in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a stock dataframe:

```
   Open     High      Low    Close  Volume        rb          us  \
0  1.20821  1.20821  1.20793  1.20794  138.96  0.022347  100.000000   
1  1.20794  1.20795  1.20787  1.20788  119.61  0.004967   85.714286   
2  1.20788  1.20793  1.20770  1.20779  210.42  0.007451   64.285714   
3  1.20779  1.20791  1.20779  1.20789   77.51  0.008280   83.333333   
4  1.20789  1.20795  1.20789  1.20792   56.97  0.002484   50.000000   

           ls  color  
0   96.428571  black  
1   85.714286  black  
2   50.000000  black  
3  100.000000  white  
4  100.000000  white
```

I want to compare current row data to previous row data,something like this:

```
if(df['color'] == df['color'].shift(-1)):
   if((df['Close'] >= df['Open'].shift(-1) and df['Open']>=df['Close'].shift(-1)):
      df['Position'] = UP
   if((df['Close'] < df['Open'].shift(-1) and df['Open']<=df['Close'].shift(-1)):
      df['Position'] = DOWN
```

THERE ARE MANY MORE IF CONDITIONS ...

It's not possible to compare data by

```
np.where(condition,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Because of many conditions I have in my algorithm. It's just part of them.

How can I do these conditions check?

Comment: Would it be ok to create separate columns for each condition? That way you can compare rows for true condition @Behdad Ahmadi

Comment: @Biarys I want to make a model and then compile it with Keras for Deep Learning solution.  If I create separate columns,the model will be so bad for Deep Learning.

Answer (score 8):

You need:

```
df['Position'] = np.where((df['Volume'] > df['Volume'].shift(-1)) & ((df['Close'] >= df['Close'].shift(-1)) & (df['Open'] <= df['Open'])),"UP","DOWN")
```

Output:

```
        Open    High    Low Close   Volume  Position
0   1.20821 1.20821 1.20793 1.20794 138.96  UP
1   1.20794 1.20795 1.20787 1.20788 119.61  DOWN
2   1.20788 1.20793 1.20770 1.20779 210.42  DOWN
3   1.20779 1.20791 1.20779 1.20789 77.51   DOWN
4   1.20789 1.20795 1.20789 1.20792 56.97   DOWN
```

Comment: I think your answer looks into the future

Comment: Look at OP's conditions. May be the df is sorted in reverse order with time? Since we do not have timestamps, we cannot comment on that. @Biarys

Comment: I have never seen stock time series data with most recent dates on top, but I guess that's possible @Harv Ipan

Answer (score 2):

I would divide it in different check-ups:

```
diffdf = df.diff()[1:]

cond1 = diffdf['Volume'] > 0
cond2 = diffdf['Close'] >= 0
# cond3 = diffdf['Open'] >= 0 ?? What is this supposed to check?

df['Position'] = np.insert(np.where(cond1&cond2, 'UP', 'DOWN'), 0, '-')
```

`df.diff()`:

```
      Open     High      Low    Close  Volume
0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN
1 -0.00027 -0.00026 -0.00006 -0.00006  -19.35
2 -0.00006 -0.00002 -0.00017 -0.00009   90.81
3 -0.00009 -0.00002  0.00009  0.00010 -132.91
4  0.00010  0.00004  0.00010  0.00003  -20.54
```

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = '''\
Open     High      Low    Close  Volume
1.20821  1.20821  1.20793  1.20794  138.96
1.20794  1.20795  1.20787  1.20788  119.61
1.20788  1.20793  1.20770  1.20779  210.42
1.20779  1.20791  1.20779  1.20789   77.51
1.20789  1.20795  1.20789  1.20792   56.97'''

fileobj = pd.compat.StringIO(data)
df = pd.read_csv(fileobj, sep='\s+')

# Our client wants to know what stocks have increased in Volumne and Close
# We call this element Position and it is either Up,Down,-
# Let us create a difference dataframe and check those conditions
diffdf = df.diff()[1:]
cond1 = diffdf['Volume'] > 0
cond2 = diffdf['Close'] >= 0
df['Position'] = np.insert(np.where(cond1&cond2, 'UP', 'DOWN'), 0, '-')

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
      Open     High      Low    Close  Volume Position
0  1.20821  1.20821  1.20793  1.20794  138.96        -
1  1.20794  1.20795  1.20787  1.20788  119.61     DOWN
2  1.20788  1.20793  1.20770  1.20779  210.42     DOWN
3  1.20779  1.20791  1.20779  1.20789   77.51     DOWN
4  1.20789  1.20795  1.20789  1.20792   56.97     DOWN
```

Comment: condColor_BLACK_BLACK = diffdf['color'] == 'black' & diffdf['color'] == 'black'

How can I check this condition,it returns error :TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: @BehdadAhmadi Do you have colors in your data? I don't understand.

Comment: I mention the dataframe in question in very simple structure because of many complex structure.

Comment: @BehdadAhmadi Ok sure.

Comment: @BehdadAhmadi Ok but try to explain what Black has to do with it?

Comment: if CLOSE > OPEN => COLOR = WHITE,and otherwise is BLACK i am making a model for ANN

Comment: @BehdadAhmadi Sorry... but your question is far from clear in my opinion. I cannot help you further atm.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing your time with me. You helped me a lot.